# PHP - stripos() not working on file contents - always returning false

Tags: php

I'm building a *very* simple search function for my website, but strangely the `stripos` function is not behaving like it aught to. I've used `gettype`, `is_string`, `settype`, and many other functions to echo every step I take, and it all seems to work until I get to the variable `$found`. I've read many other questions related to this but I can't seem to find the answer. I read somewhere that when using a variable as the needle in the `strpos` function, I need to put it in quotes, so I did that for *my* `stripos`, but that didn't fix the problem.

Also, just a side question: why do i need to put my `$search` variable inside `print_r` and `htmlspecialchars`? If I don't and then try echoing with `gettype()`, it returns NULL...? Thanks in advance. The code:

```
<?php
    /*------------------------VARIABLES------------------------*/
    $search = $_GET['search'];
    $numberOfResults = 0;
    $fileContents;
    $found;
    $contentsLength;
    $startSearch;
    $endSearch;
    $contentsSearchLength;

    /*------------------------FUNCTIONS------------------------*/
    function displaySearch() {
        //I'd have thought I don't need the below line but it returns NULL if I don't... found the script somewhere in the docs
        $search = htmlspecialchars(print_r($search, true));
        foreach (glob('search/this/directory/*.*') as $file) {
            $fileContents = file_get_contents($file);
            //these next five lines narrow the file contents down to the body of the content of the file -- I don't want to search scripts, styling, or links!
            $contentsLength = strlen($fileContents);
            $startSearch = strpos($fileContents, '<div id="body">');
            $endSearch = strpos($fileContents, '<!--FOOTER-->');
            $contentsSearchLength = $contentsLength - ($contentsLength - $endSearch) - $startSearch;
            $fileContents = strip_tags(substr($fileContents, $startSearch, $contentsSearchLength));
            $numberOfResultsInFile = 0;
            $found = stripos($fileContents, "$search");
            if ($found !== false) {
                $numberOfResults += 1;
                echo '<div class="results" id="result'.$numberOfResults.'">';
                    echo '<div class="title">';
                        echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$file.'">Result'.$numberOfResults.'</a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div id="preview">';
                        echo 'Preview of file contents here';       
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            } else {
                //move on to next file
            }
        }
        if ($numberOfResults == 0) {
            echo 'No results could be found';
        }
    }
?>
<h1>Search Results for "<?php echo $search ?>":</h1>
<br>
<div id="results">
    <?php   
        if (empty($search)) {
            echo 'Please enter a search query or go back to the <a href="home.php">Home Page</a>';
        } else {
            displaySearch();
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Resolved: had to pass, instead of `$search`, `$_GET['search']` directly to the `stripos` function.

Comment: Pass $search directly: `$found = stripos($fileContents, $search);`

Comment: I've tried that, but it still returns false still

Comment: Try `exit(var_dump($search));` and see what is $search.

Comment: Just out of curiosity does it fail if you substitute $search in the stripos with $_GET['search']? Also, are you sure $search is not null when it gets to the stripos?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob thanks, you hit the nail on the head

Comment: Glad I could help! Feel free to upvote my comment as useful :)

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Sorry, but I don't see how to do that. It's probably because I'm new to stack overflow (I don't have any reputation) so it's not available to me.